# PhpUnit bootstrap arguments

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a phpunit.xml which defines what tests to test and where the bootstrap file is.
I also want to define parameters in my phpunit.xml that can be accessed during the bootstrap.

Here's my phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php" colors="true" bootstrapArg="abcdefgh">
    <testsuite name="TestSuite">

        <file>./Test1.php</file>
        <file>./Test2.php</file>

</testsuite></phpunit>
```

I want to access the value of "bootstrapArg" in my bootstrap.php. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The configuration can contain a `<php>` section following the rules [described in the manual](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.php-ini-constants-variables):

```
<php>
  <includePath>.</includePath>
  <ini name="foo" value="bar"/>
  <const name="foo" value="bar"/>
  <var name="foo" value="bar"/>
  <env name="foo" value="bar"/>
  <post name="foo" value="bar"/>
  <get name="foo" value="bar"/>
  <cookie name="foo" value="bar"/>
  <server name="foo" value="bar"/>
  <files name="foo" value="bar"/>
  <request name="foo" value="bar"/>
</php>
```

What will lead to the following bootstrap code:

```
ini_set('foo', 'bar');
define('foo', 'bar');
$GLOBALS['foo'] = 'bar';
$_ENV['foo'] = 'bar';
$_POST['foo'] = 'bar';
$_GET['foo'] = 'bar';
$_COOKIE['foo'] = 'bar';
$_SERVER['foo'] = 'bar';
$_FILES['foo'] = 'bar';
$_REQUEST['foo'] = 'bar';
```

You can access those vars during the bootstrap process.